# "Edit with Idle" doesn't open the file as expected

Tags: python, windows-10, python-idle, python-3.8

I need help in python 3.8. When I right-click on a Python script and select "Edit with Idle", it never opens, yet it makes a folder named `_pycache_`. Am using Windows 10.

Comment: What's the name of the script?

Answer (score 1):

If your file is named with a Python keyterm (eg print.py) then it will create the *pycache* folder when it attempts to link and interpret the code in the file. (Then crash and fail to run, as your file is now replacing the Python library file).

Comment: Best to ask what the filename is before providing this kind of answer.

Comment: Thanks very much, I searched  for a solution to this problem many times and I don't find anything you are the best thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

The registry entry you're looking for is found here.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Python.File\shell\Edit with IDLE\command
```

Hit start and type "registry editor" then paste that in the address bar.
You will be able to see where that context menu button is pointing at and fix it if need be.
[Registry Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNhWF.png)